# Getting a value from a complex JSON file (multiple objects inside an object)

Tags: json, parsing, jsonparser, jsonobjectrequest

I am trying to get a value from a JSON file, however it is a complex JSON file and i'm not sure how to go about it.

The value is situated inside an object, that is inside another object, which inside another object.

The values I want to retrieve from the JSON file is "value" and "unit" situated inside the object "metric". I have been able to successfully retrieve the "name" value.

The JSON file:

```
    {
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "breakfast sausage",
      "image": "breakfast-sausage-links.jpg",
      "amount": {
        "metric": {
          "value": 226.796,
          "unit": "g"
        },
        "us": {
          "value": 8,
          "unit": "ounces"
        }
      }
    },
```

I will also include the method that I parse the JSON from:

```
private void jsonParse(){
    String url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/"+ rMealId + "/ingredientWidget.json?&apiKey=da7dd16a704f4552b70a96c1e9641b08";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("ingredients");

                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject ingredients = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String iName = ingredients.getString("name");

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Can you use jsonpath?

Comment: Hi Jack,no I have never heard of jsonpath, do you know how I would go about this, or if there are any tutorials or related questions based on this?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath

Comment: If you're interested, I can show you how that would work with the json you have in your question.

Comment: Hello Jack, yes please that would be very helpful as I am not really sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

Just focusing on your json string, try this:

```
let ings =
 {
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "breakfast sausage",
      "image": "breakfast-sausage-links.jpg",
      "amount": {
        "metric": {
          "value": 226.796,
          "unit": "g"
        },
        "us": {
          "value": 8,
          "unit": "ounces"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

let jp = require('jsonpath');
let eat = jp.query(ings, '$..metric.*');
console.log(eat);
```

output:

> [ 226.796, 'g' ]

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you so much, however you wouldn't by any chance know how to do this in Java ? I have created my code using java and therefore am not familiar with the language you have used

Comment: @DearbhlaMcMullen - I'm afraid not.

Comment: Does the jsonparsing still work if I am getting the JSON file from a http url? Also there are still other JSON objects inside the jsonFile,  I just took a snippet of the JSON file.

Comment: And no worries at all, thank you for trying to help anyway :)

Comment: @DearbhlaMcMullen - The source of the json strings is irrelevant to jsonpath; but you need to be able to fish those strings out with correct json format intact ... Good luck.